# Altair stream graph with labels

Tags: python, altair

I was able to produce a nice stream graph in Altair and would like to add labels  instead of a legend. I followed this example https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/stacked_bar_chart_with_text.html, but it seemingly assigns a label to each data point.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.unemployment_across_industries.url

stream = (
    alt.Chart(source)
    .mark_area()
    .encode(
        alt.X(
            "yearmonth(date):T", axis=alt.Axis(format="%Y", domain=False, tickSize=0)
        ),
        alt.Y("sum(count):Q", stack="center", axis=None),
        alt.Color("series:N", scale=alt.Scale(scheme="category20b")),
    )
)

text = (
    alt.Chart(source)
    .mark_text(dx=-15, dy=3, color='white')
    .encode(
       alt.X(
            "yearmonth(date):T", axis=alt.Axis(format="%Y", domain=False, tickSize=0)
        ),
        alt.Y("sum(count):Q", stack="center", axis=None),
        alt.Color("series:N", scale=alt.Scale(scheme="category20b")),
        detail="series:N",
        text=alt.Text("series:N", format=".1f"),
    )
)

stream + text
```

Alternatively I tried this, but it just gets worse.

```
text = stream.mark_text(
align="left",
baseline="middle",
dx=3, 
).encode(text="series:N")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are specifying ``month(date)`` as the x-encoding for your text, which means that you want a text mark for each month. If you want a single text mark, you should use an aggregate or a single value instead. I'd answer your question, but you've not made clear what your expected output actually is. Where do you expect the text marks to appear?

Comment: I'd like the labels to be in the middle of each area like this: https://public.tableau.com/profile/ryansoares#!/vizhome/MusicIndustrySales/Dashboard1

Comment: This is fairly straightforward depending on what data you are visualizing, but it really doesn't seem like there's enough room in the chart created by your code above to put labels on each area.

Comment: Agreed. I was just using that data as an example though and I have more room in my actual dataset. Maybe I'm approaching this too much from a Tableau perspective and I won't necessarily use this, but I'd like to know how it works as a PoC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dataframe to be used specifically for the labelling:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.unemployment_across_industries().query("series in ['Agriculture', 'Finance']")

stream = (
    alt.Chart(source)
    .mark_area()
    .encode(
        alt.X("yearmonth(date):T", axis=alt.Axis(format="%Y")),
        alt.Y("sum(count):Q", stack="center", axis=None),
        alt.Color("series:N", scale=alt.Scale(scheme="category20b"))))

text_df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['2005', '2005'], 'y': [650, 450], 'text': ['Agriculture', 'Finance']})
stream + alt.Chart(text_df).mark_text(color='white').encode(
    x='x:T',
    y='y',
    text='text')
```

[image]